# Can't delete AKS

Tags: azure-aks

I can't delete my AKS instance. When attempting to do so I receive an 'internal server error' with no further information. I then proceeded to delete the infrastructure resource group which worked, but still couldn't delete the namespace.

Tried portal, CLI and PowerShell.

Comment: Are you using the portal or the az cli?

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure portal -> Activity log you can view details of the failure.

Had the same issue, my problem was that a security group assigned to an aks vnet couldn't get deleted:

> Deletion of resource group 'MC_ReG_aks-olymp-d_aks-olymp-d_westeurope' failed as resources with identifiers 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/aks-agentpool-35064155-nsg' could not be deleted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately in my case I don't get more info.

Comment: Check your route table, it might have associated subnets.